# How to make textfield readonly if value in shuttle is not selected

Tags: oracle-adf, jdeveloper

I have a textfield and would like to not make it read only if a value is selected from a shuttle (many options can be picked). I am using Jheadstart to create the page, but an adf solution works just as well as I can just insert that change into ta template.Normally I would use a binding and select the input value of of another field, but I am not sure what to select with the shuttle as a shuttle can have many selections.

Answer (score 0):

To get the values from the shuttlebox inside a bean:

```
BindingContainer myBC = this.getBindings();
JUCtrlListBinding listBinding = (JUCtrlListBinding)myBC.get("ViewObject1"); //viewObject that populates the shuttflebox
Object str[] = listBinding.getSelectedValues();
if(str.length>0)
    isTextBoxDisabled=false;
else
    isTextBoxDisabled=true;
```

Then bind the Disabled property of the inputtext to myBean.isTextBoxDisabled

This would need a page submit in order to activate, so I'm guessing that's not what you are after.

If you want it to automatically update the values as their are moved around in the shuttle, you will have to use the ValueChangeListener property of the shuttle, in which to get the size of the selections.

```
public void selectValueChangeListener(ValueChangeEvent valueChangeEvent) {
   ArrayList list = new ArrayList(Arrays.asList(valueChangeEvent.getNewValue()));
   if(list.isEmpty())
      isTextBoxDisabled=true;
   else
      isTextBoxDisabled=false;
  //refresh the inputText component
  AdfFacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addPartialTarget(myInputText);
}
```

Bear in mind the ValueChangeListener will only get processed via their bean method when the page is submitted. If you want the change processed when changing the value of the shuttle, set autoSubmit = true.